# Is it possible to build HTML5 applications without a server?

Tags: javascript, json, html, user-interface, webserver

I am working on a hobby project that tests some content available in  a remote database mostly Oracle and MSSQL. I really don't see the need for a server as I can do my logic in `Javascript` and it is an overhead to run the server if it only does:

1. Hit DB
2. Return JSON

Is that possible or do I really need a back-end server because of client side restrictions? Basically I am thinking along the lines of `Chrome App's` in terms of look and feel i.e standalone Windows built using `HTML5` but I don't know if all of them have to use a server.

Can I achieve this in `Client` side itself? I doubt `JSON` would be possible unless some Database responds in `JSON` format.

Comment: a server  .. or a web .server .. you can work locally with a local webserver .. tipically   the testing application work on  localhost .. and if you don't need  php or mysql  access  you ca avoid and use only the browser withou web server

Comment: where u gonna store the user data of your application ? in sqlite of html5 ?

Comment: I am going to read stuff from a Database. I don't see any need for modifying the data at the moment. Its for a Testing suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server is needed only if you use server-based technologies, like PHP and MySQL. So as long as you stay with HTML, CSS and Javascript, you won't need one.

Comment: I do need to contact a remote DB.

Comment: well, then you need a server. But you don't necessarily need an external one, something like XAMPP (which runs the server software on your computer) is sufficient.

Comment: is that because you can't do database access from client? that is the only reason or is there more to it?

Comment: "client" already imples that there has to be a server... Often a webserver has to parse code (like PHP) and also access a database in order to return the desired data as HTML code